# Redmine returns JSON with word "issues" padded in start

Tags: json, extjs, redmine, redmine-api

I have setup Redmine locally. I want to Get and Post data on Red mine in order to test my Extjs application.
Redmine RestApi support is available. 
This link show all the issue on Redmine available
http://www.redmine.org/issues.json

Problem is that it is padded with word "issues" due to which I can't read it via simple Json type reader in Extjs.
I guess JSONP can provide some solution but I am not able to figure out how?
Can any help by telling how to get simple JSON without and padded word?

Here is my Extjs app Model:

```
Ext.define('ThemeApp.model.peopleModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    { name: 'id' },

    { name: 'subject' },

    { name: 'description'}
],

proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    format: 'json',
    limitParam:"",
    filterParam: "",

    url:'http://www.redmine.org/issues.json',

    //headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" },
    //url : 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=allah%20dita%20rehman%20khan&client_id=0b19b8dc2526b43eae19f03b2eab6798&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200'

    reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty:'issues'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }

}});
```

Error in Browser Console is 
[image: Browser Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redmine returns valid JSON (as can be checked [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)), so the ExtJS JSON reader can read it without a problem.

You will just have to tell him where to search, by setting the [root](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-root) property (ExtJS 4) or the [rootProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-rootProperty) property (ExtJS 5)  on the reader.

ExtJS4:

```
reader:{
    type:'json',
    root:'issues'
}
```

ExtJS5:

```
reader:{
    type:'json',
    rootProperty:'issues'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the rootProperty Property properly, 
But I still can't access data, 
Now my browser console shows this error:
"Image is attached in Updated Question"

Comment: What error? I don't see it. But my best guess would be that you are not allowed to read JSON data from a different domain.

Comment: I am using CORS Chrome extension to read data from different domain. 
I have tried reading Soundcloud api and It worked properly, but with Redmine I am facing issues.

Comment: @YawarKhan In the image, I see that you are trying to request `issues.json.json`. IIRC the link is `issues.json`. This would of course yield a `404`.